# Shell Font Over SSH

Tags: linux, shell, centos, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have a Linux machine (CentOS 7) in which I frequently SSH into from multiple devices. I have installed ZSH and Oh-my-zsh on the remote machine. I would like to install the following theme: https://gist.github.com/agnoster/3712874 however I'm unsure of how fonts and colors work. Will I have to install the special font required by this theme on each device from which I am connecting to the remote machine, or can I install the fonts and colors all on the remote machine, so that no matter which terminal I connect from, it will always look the same (with the theme and colors I select). The root of my question comes from the fact that I don't understand whether these stylistic attributes are derived from the client or the remote machine. Any conceptual as well as practical explanation would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Your fonts and colors would be determined by the type of terminal emulator and where *it* is run.  Some people do something like

```
ssh -X remotehost -e xterm
```

and some do this

```
ssh
```

(running in a terminal on the *local* host).  Technically the local X display determines the maximum number of colors which you can use (in either case), but most users have displays which exceed their likely use.

Where fonts come from depends on the application:

- fontconfig gets its information from the machine where it is run (use [`fc-list`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fc-list) to see this), while
- bitmap fonts come from the remote server (use [`xlsfonts`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xlsfonts) to see this).